# How to reference object methods in a class variable in Python

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I have this class which works :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.checks = (self.check1, self.check2)

    def check1(self):
        print("check1")

    def check2(self):
        print("check2")

    def run_all_checks(self):
        for check in self.checks:
            check()

a = A()

a.run_all_checks()
```

Now I think attribute `checks` should not belong to every A object, but should be a class attribute, so I'd like to write :

```
class A:
    checks = (self.check1, self.check2)

    def check1(self):
        print("check1")

    def check2(self):
        print("check2")

    def run_all_checks(self):
        for check in self.checks:
            check()

a = A()

a.run_all_checks()
```

This version does not work, giving error :

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: "Now I think attribute `checks` should not belong to every A object, but should be a class attribute" - why do you think that? It sounds like you're mistaken.

Comment: Making `checks` a property would enable you to use the syntax you want to use in `run_all_checks()`.

Comment: @user2357112 If I have a million objects, attribute `checks` would take space for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) probably gets you closest to what you're trying to achieve.

This way, `self.checks` gives the tuple of the two check functions, but it does so through a getter function that's called on the fly: so there's no extra storage requirement (albeit that storing two references to functions doesn't take much space).

```
class A:
    @property
    def checks(self):
        return (self.check1, self.check2)

    def check1(self):
        print("check1")

    def check2(self):
        print("check2")

    def run_all_checks(self):
        for check in self.checks:
            check()

a = A()

a.run_all_checks()
```

which as expected prints

```
check1
check2
```

Comment: `storing two references to functions doesn't take much space` It would take much space if I have many objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference `check1` and `check2` before they've been defined, and you also have to keep in mind that in the scope of the class definition, there is no `self`.

You can have a class attribute that references the methods, but since they won't have a `self` automatically bound to them, the caller will need to supply it:

```
class A:
    def check1(self):
        print("check1")

    def check2(self):
        print("check2")

    checks = (check1, check2)

    def run_all_checks(self):
        for check in self.checks:
            check(self)

a = A()

a.run_all_checks()
```